# What is the difference between anchored position and local position in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am new to unity. I am trying to figure out what is the difference between anchored position and local position and where can the both be applied?

Answer (score -1):

## Anchored Position

The Anchored Position is the position of the pivot of the RectTransform taking into consideration the anchor reference point. The anchor reference point is the position of the anchors. If the anchors are not together, Unity estimates the four anchor positions using the pivot placement as a reference.

## Local Position

localPosition is the position of the GameObject with respect to its parent object. transform. position is the position of the GameObject with respect to the root. Within local space of a GameObject, the center (or pivot) is always (0, 0, 0).

**Source: Unity Forum**

Comment: Could you please describe what is "anchor reference point" and how Unity estimates  four anchor positions using the pivot placement?

Comment: It is the position of the anchors. If the anchors are not together, Unity estimates the four anchor positions using the pivot placement as a reference.

Comment: Anyone asking this question would have also searched the unity docs. 
This is not helpful.

Comment: Copy paste from Unity docs. Not helpful.

Comment: It is indeed from unity forum. I did mention it.